# Need help in Database Schema Design for a printshop product options

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, activerecord

I have been working on a Print Shop website lately. And I am now having trouble in developing an efficient database schema.

My application is a Printshop which offers custom Prints for Posters, Business Cards and Flyers etc. 
The problem I am facing is in developing the schema for product options.
Here is a scenario: 
A Business Card can have "Size" and "Material" options. The "Size" can be "3.5x2.5 inches" or "3.25x2.25 inches". Similarly "Material" can be "300 gsm Card Stock" or "200 gsm Card Stock". 
Now what my store offers is the price for options and quantity combinations .

Like, 
`100 Business Cards + 3.5x2.5 inch + 300 gsm Card Stock = $500.00`

or

`200 Business Cards + 3.5x2.5 inch + 300 gsm Card Stock = $800.00`.

One point to be noting here is that the "Size" option is different for "Flyers" and "Posters" products. So a "3.5x2.5" Poster just doesn't make sense. The poster product will have its own sizes. The prices are always bound to the options combinations, there is no individual prices for the products without options combinations.

Secondly, there is weight based shipping too. So I would also like to know, where to store the weight in the database?

Please provide some insights about designing such a database. Also I would like an ActiveRecord based approach since I am too weak in EAV Modelling.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

**`Products`**:

- `ProductId` Primary key,
- `ProductName`,
- ...

**`Materials`**:

- `MaterialID` Primary key,
- `MaterialName`.

**`Units`**:

- `UnitId` Primary Key,
- `UnitName`.

**`ProductsSizesOptions`**:

- `SizeOptionId` Primary Key,
- `Height`,
- `Width`,
- `UnitId` Foreign Key constraint `REFERENCES Units(UnitId)` to handle different types of unit for each product.

**`ProductsMaterialOptions`**:

- `MaterialOptionId`,
- `Quantity`,
- `MaterialId` Foreign key constraint `REFERENCES Materials(MaterialId)` to handle different types of materials for each product's offers .

**`ProductsOffers`**:

- `OfferId` Primary key,
- `ProductId` Foreign key constraint `REFERENCES Products(ProductId)`,
- `MaterialOptionId` Foreign key constraint REFERENCES ProductsMaterialOptions(MaterialOptionId)`,
- `SizeOptionId` Foreign key constraint `REFERENCES ProductsSizesOptions(SizeOptionId)` ,
- `Price`.

[image]

---

For example, for the sample data you posted in you question, you can simple get these offers for each product by `JOIN`ing the tables:

```
SELECT
  po.OfferId,
  p.ProductNAme,
  mo.Quantity,
  m.MaterialName,
  so.Height,
  so.width,
  u.UnitName,
  po.Price
FROM products                      AS p
INNER JOIN ProductsOffers          AS po ON p.ProductId         = po.ProductId
INNER JOIN ProductsMaterialOptions AS mo ON po.MaterialOptionId = mo.MaterialOptionId
INNER JOIN ProductsSizesOptions    AS so ON so.SizeOptionId     = po.SizeOptionId
INNER JOIN Units                   AS u  ON u.UnitId            = so.unitId
INNER JOIN Materials               AS m  ON m.MaterialId        = m.MaterialId;
```

This will give you something like:

```
| OFFERID |   PRODUCTNAME | QUANTITY | MATERIALNAME | HEIGHT | WIDTH | UNITNAME | PRICE |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1 | Business Card |      100 |   Card Stock |      4 |     3 |      gsm |   500 |
|       2 | Business Card |      200 |   Card Stock |      4 |     3 |      gsm |   800 |
```

Then from your front end application you can format these results the way you wish.

### [SQL Fiddle Demo For DB schema](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/820cf/2)

---

### Update

**`Products`:**

- `ProductId`,
- `ProductName`,
- ...

**`Options`:**

- `OptionId`,
- `OptionName`.

To store the possible options:

```
OptionId OptionName
1 Material
2 Shape
and so on
```

**`Properties`:**

- `PropertyId`,
- `PropertyName`,
- `PropertyTypeId`.

**`PropertiesTypes`:**

- `PropertyTypeId`,
- `PropertyTypeName`.

You might not need this table, but you might use it from your front end application to know how to display this field on your application. For example it may contain these values:

```
1 Integer
2 String
3 Decimal
...
```

**`OptionsProperties`:**

- `OptionPropertyId`,
- `OptionId`,
- `PropertyId`.

The properties for each option, for example `Shape` and `Material`:

```
OptionPropertyId OptionId PropertyId 
1                   1        1
2                   2        2
3                   2        3
4                   2        4
```

**`ProductOptions`:**

- `ProductOptionId`,
- `ProductId`,
- `OptionId`.

**`ProductOptionsValues`:**

- `ProductOfferOptionsId`,
- `ProductId`,
- `PropertyId`,
- `NumericValue`,
- `TXTValue`.

**`ProductsOffers`:**

- `OfferId`,
- `ProductOfferOptionsId`,
- `Quantity`,
- `Price`.

[image]

so you can get a list of offers for each product like this:

```
SELECT
  p.ProductName,
  MAX(CASE WHEN pr.PropertyName = 'Material Name' THEN PropertyValue END) AS 'Material Name',
  MAX(CASE WHEN pr.PropertyName = 'Height' THEN PropertyValue END) AS 'Height',
  MAX(CASE WHEN pr.PropertyName = 'Width' THEN PropertyValue END) AS 'Width',
  MAX(CASE WHEN pr.PropertyName = 'Unit' THEN PropertyValue END) AS 'Unit',
  o.Quantity,
  o.Price
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    ProductId,
    PropertyId,
    ProductOfferOptionsId, 
    COALESCE(NumericValue, TXTValue) AS PropertyValue
  FROM 
  ProductOptionsValues
) AS ov ON ov.ProductId = p.ProductId
INNER JOIN OptionsProperties AS op ON op.PropertyId            = ov.PropertyId
INNER JOIN Properties        AS pr ON op.PropertyId            = pr.PropertyId
INNER JOIN ProductsOffers    AS o  ON o.ProductOfferOptionsId  = ov.ProductOfferOptionsId 
GROUP BY p.ProductName,
         o.Quantity,
         o.Price;
```

This will give you:

```
|   PRODUCTNAME |  MATERIAL NAME | HEIGHT | WIDTH | UNIT | QUANTITY | PRICE |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Business Card | gsm Card Stock |    3.5 |   2.5 | inch |      100 |   500 |
| Business Card | gsm Card Stock |    3.5 |   2.5 | inch |      200 |   800 |
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99885/1)

---

This query, ofcourse, doesn't make sense. To get a list of all properties you have to do this dynamically using dynamic SQL. You can put the following code in a stored procedure:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(pr.PropertyName = ''',
      pr.PropertyName, ''', ov.PropertyValue, 0)) AS ', '''',   pr.PropertyName , '''')
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Properties        AS pr 
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    PropertyId,
    COALESCE(NumericValue, TXTValue) AS PropertyValue
  FROM 
  ProductOptionsValues
) AS ov ON pr.PropertyId = ov.PropertyId;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT
  p.ProductName, ', @sql , ', o.Quantity,
  o.Price
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    ProductId,
    PropertyId,
    ProductOfferOptionsId, 
    COALESCE(NumericValue, TXTValue) AS PropertyValue
  FROM 
  ProductOptionsValues
) AS ov ON ov.ProductId = p.ProductId
INNER JOIN OptionsProperties AS op ON op.PropertyId            = ov.PropertyId
INNER JOIN Properties        AS pr ON op.PropertyId            = pr.PropertyId
INNER JOIN ProductsOffers    AS o  ON o.ProductOfferOptionsId  = ov.ProductOfferOptionsId 
GROUP BY   p.ProductName,
  o.Quantity,
  o.Price');



prepare stmt 
FROM @sql;

execute stmt;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99885/5)

This will pivot all the properties dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but according to your suggested schema, A product can have only two options "Size" and "Material". What if, more options are added to the product in future?

Comment: @khalid - For limited number of options, you can add tables for each option `ProductFooOptions` otherwise use EVA with key and value for each options.

Comment: Can you please also provide an EAV example for ProductOptions. I don't know much about how EAV works, so a schema will definitely help.

Comment: @khalid - See my edit. Note that this EVA model is not recommended I am not a professional in this data model. It is too hard, and it will require heavy work from the front end application. **Don't use it** Unless you really really need it. And sorry for late.

Comment: Thanks for the updated reply. I am also preparing a schema on the basis of all the suggestions posted in this thread. Hopefully something better would definitely come out.

Answer (score 2):

You are selling items from a Catalog. An item can be either a Good (which is really the specification of a product and not a physical asset), or a collection of goods, which is called a Marketing Package.

You need to use [Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) here.

```
catalog_item
------------
id
type {good, marketing_package}
name

good : catalog_item
-------------------
size
material

marketing_package : catalog_item
--------------------------------
standard_price

marketing_package_good (this is a junction table)
----------------------
marketing_package_id
good_id
quantity

poster : good
-------------
{any poster-specific properties or defaults}


flyer : good
------------
{any flyer-specific properties or defaults}


business_card : good
--------------------
{any business-card-specific properties or defaults}
```